# Front panel mic are not getting detected in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, 19.10, microphone, audio-jack

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my desktop. I installed it as dual-boot alongside Windows.

It's not detecting the front panel microphone, but it's detecting my headphones, and it works.

I have tried every possible solution from the internet (like alsamixer,pulse-audio, etc.), but nothing worked for me. My Windows detects excellently, but Ubuntu did not recognize my microphone.

How can I fix this?

Here shows an input device name internal microphone-build-in audio that's not collect any sound.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your release, you mention 19.04 in tags & title, but question refers to 19.10

Comment: Now I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.